# video js ie9 multiple urls on one page

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, video.js

I have an object of video urls like so:

```
  var urls = new Object();

  urls['cail_ivt'] = {'mp4_url': http://link_to_.mp4', 'webm_url': 'http://link_to_.webm', 'flv_url': 'http://link_to_.flv' };

  urls['cail_ty'] = {'mp4_url': 'http://link_to_.mp4', 'webm_url': 'http://link_to_.webm', 'flv_url': 'http://link_to_.flv' };

  urls['cail_1'] = {'mp4_url':       'http://link_to_.mp4', 'webm_url': 'http://link_to_.webm', 'flv_url': 'http://link_to_.flv' };

  urls['cail_2'] = {'mp4_url': 'http://link_to_.mp4', 'webm_url': 'http://link_to_.webm', 'flv_url': 'http://link_to_.flv' };

  urls['cail_3'] = {'mp4_url': 'http://link_to_.mp4', 'webm_url': 'http://link_to_.webm', 'flv_url': 'http://link_to_.flv' };


_V_.options.flash.swf = 'http://static_server/video-js.swf';
```

I have a bunch of anchor tags who's id is the key to the urls object:

I then wrote a little js to bind those anchor clicks and load the appropriate video into the player div and display it. It never displays and doesn't play. This only seems to happen in ie9.

```
    $('ul a.play_button').click(function() {

    var campaign_id = $(this).attr('id');

    var mp4_url  = urls[campaign_id].mp4_url;
    var webm_url = urls[campaign_id].webm_url;
    var flv_url  = urls[campaign_id].flv_url;   

    var video_player = '<video id="video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="640" height="360" poster="" data-setup="{}"> '
                                   + '<source id="mp4"   src="'+mp4_url+'" type="video/mp4" />'
                                   + '<source id="flash" src="'+flv_url+'" type="video/flv" />'
                                   + '<source id="webm"  src="'+webm_url+'" type="video/webm" />'
                                   + '</video>';
    $('#player').empty();
    $('#player').html(video_player);                                
});
```

Not sure if this is the best way to handle multiple videos in a player but it's what I came up with. Discussion and help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to my other issue with videojs. I had to declare a variable set to the player:

```
 var mplayer = _V_('video');
```

when I load other videos on the same page I simply pause the player, rewind it back to the beginning of the video and set the new video sources:

```
 mplayer.pause();
 mplayer.currentTime(0);
 mplayer.src([{ type: "video/mp4", src: mp4_url },{ type: "video/webm", src: webm_url },{ type: "video/flv", src: flv_url }]);
```